# How to use "union" across more than two columns in R?

Tags: r, string, compare

I am trying to compare columns in a data.frame to identify the unique values across multiple columns. I have data on multiple individuals which I've converted from long to wide format and want to identify all the values for an individual.

```
df <- data_frame(ID=rep(1:10,3), Value = as.character(rep(list("A1,B7,B11,C2","A1,B5,B8,D3",""),10)))
```

This gives an example of what a subset of the data might look like (might not be the neatest way of achieving this but seemed to work)

I have started with:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(Value, ~na_if(., ""))) %>%
  within({time <- ave(ID, list=ID, FUN=seq_along)}) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols="ID",names_from="time",names_prefix="Value",values_from="Value") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Value = union(
    str_split(Value1, ",", simplify = TRUE),
    str_split(Value2, ",", simplify = TRUE)
  ) |> str_c(collapse = ", "))
```

This works perfectly for the first two columns generated, but I'm not sure how best to incorporate the third column (or further columns in general as there are often 5 or more).

I had considered a loop with each new column being compared to the output from the previous loop but thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: Do you like to compare every column pairwisely, i.e. column1 with column2, column1 with column3, or just column1 with column2, column2 with column3, ....

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, I'm trying to get all the unique values for an individual so across all the columns for which an individual has values, after converting from long to wide (or via another method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to do but this does *identify the unique values* across multiple rows within a group.

Starting with the original `df`, first `strsplit` to get the single values from the string, then finding the `unique` values and finally `paste` together the result.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  reframe(Value = paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(Value, ","))), 
                    collapse=", "), .by = ID)
# A tibble: 10 × 2
      ID Value                      
   <int> <chr>                      
 1     1 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
 2     2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
 3     3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
 4     4 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
 5     5 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
 6     6 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
 7     7 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
 8     8 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
 9     9 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
10    10 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
Value = c("A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit, if you have `NA`s and only want to keep them if it's the only value

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  reframe(Value = unique(unlist(strsplit(Value, ","))), .by = ID) %>% 
  reframe(Value = if_else(all(is.na(Value)), 
                          str_c(Value, collapse=""), 
                          str_c(na.omit(Value), collapse=", ")), .by = ID)
   ID                       Value
1   1 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
2   2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
3   3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
4   4 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
5   5 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
6   6 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
7   7 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
8   8 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
9   9 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
10 10 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
11 11                        <NA>
```

##### Data with `NA`

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
Value = c("A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", 
"A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, "A1,B7,B11,C2", "A1,B5,B8,D3", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks; almost works perfectly. The only issue (which I appreciate wasn't in the example) is that if an ID is associated with all NA values the output is "NA" as a character, is there away around this or is it easier to specify afterwards to recode as NA

Comment: Yep, paste does that intentionally and says in the help *...coerces ‘NA_character_’ ... to ‘"NA"’ which may seem undesirable...* You can use `stri_paste` for an easy fix, e.g. `library(stringi); ... Value = stri_paste(unique...`

Comment: ... or `str_c` from `stringr` has the same behavior, if you like the wrapper package better than `stringi`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, the problem is if the original data has NA instead of "", with paste the NA appears as a "unique" character in the output string, but with stri_paste str_c the whole output string becomes NA. Is there a way to exclude the NA within paste?

Comment: So basically you want to remove the `NA`s when there are other values but keep `NA` when it's the only value per group? Or do you want to remove all `NA`s? E.g. this removes all `NA`s: `df %>% reframe(Value = str_c(na.omit(unique(unlist(strsplit(Value, ",")))), collapse=", "), .by = ID)`

Comment: I've included a conditional option that keeps `NA`s if it's the only value per group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, it's to collect all unique values across an individual's rows in the Value1-Value3 variables.  If this is the case, you could first separate them by comma then find all unique values in each row and then paste them back together.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df <- tibble(ID=rep(1:10,3), Value = as.character(rep(list("A1,B7,B11,C2","A1,B5,B8,D3",""),10)))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(Value, ~na_if(., ""))) %>%
  within({time <- ave(ID, list=ID, FUN=seq_along)}) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols="ID",names_from="time",names_prefix="Value",values_from="Value") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Value = union(
    str_split(Value1, ",", simplify = TRUE),
    str_split(Value2, ",", simplify = TRUE)
  ) |> str_c(collapse = ", "))


df %>% 
  select(-Value) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Value"), ~list(str_split(.x, ",", simplify=TRUE)[1,]))) %>% 
  mutate(Value = list(na.omit(unique(c(unlist(pick(starts_with("Value")))))))) %>%
  mutate(Value = paste(Value, collapse=","))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       ID Value1    Value2    Value3    Value                
#>    <int> <list>    <list>    <list>    <chr>                
#>  1     1 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [1]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#>  2     2 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> <chr [4]> A1,B5,B8,D3,B7,B11,C2
#>  3     3 <chr [1]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#>  4     4 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [1]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#>  5     5 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> <chr [4]> A1,B5,B8,D3,B7,B11,C2
#>  6     6 <chr [1]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#>  7     7 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [1]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#>  8     8 <chr [4]> <chr [1]> <chr [4]> A1,B5,B8,D3,B7,B11,C2
#>  9     9 <chr [1]> <chr [4]> <chr [4]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
#> 10    10 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> <chr [1]> A1,B7,B11,C2,B5,B8,D3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try `reframe` like below

```
df %>%
  reframe(
    Value = list(unique(scan(
      text = Value[nzchar(Value)],
      what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE
    ))),
    .by = ID
  )
```

which gives

```
   ID                       Value
1   1 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
2   2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
3   3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
4   4 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
5   5 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
6   6 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
7   7 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
8   8 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
9   9 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
10 10 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get all the unique values for an individual so across all the columns for which an individual has values, after converting from long to wide (or via another method)

In base R we can `reshape` like (*)

```r
df$time = ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN = seq_along)
df = reshape(df, idvar = "ID", v.names = "Value", timevar = "time", direction = "w")
```

and identify unique entries row-wisely (argument: `MARGIN = 1L`) with `apply` :

```r
df$Unique = apply(df[-1L], 1L, \(x) toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))))
```

gives

```r
> df
   ID      Value.1      Value.2      Value.3                      unique
1   1 A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
2   2  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1,B7,B11,C2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
3   3              A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
4   4 A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
5   5  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1,B7,B11,C2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
6   6              A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
7   7 A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
8   8  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1,B7,B11,C2 A1, B5, B8, D3, B7, B11, C2
9   9              A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3 A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
10 10 A1,B7,B11,C2  A1,B5,B8,D3              A1, B7, B11, C2, B5, B8, D3
```

---

Data:

```r
df = data.frame(ID = rep(1:10,3), Value = as.character(rep(list("A1,B7,B11,C2","A1,B5,B8,D3",""), 10)))
```

(*) *Mimics your reshaping approach.*